# CA Service Desk Update SR Request fields

Tags: web-services

I am able to create a Service Request on CA service desk using the webservices. Now I have been given a task to update the request fields , specifically the status field which is a dropdown

I wanted to know , which method of the web service I can use to achieve this. I have been searching for the required method for quite some time , I tried out the updateObject webservice method , but that throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rubberduck Moment

I resolved this using the updateObject() of the webservice and passed a string array like below

{ "description" , "Some Test description" , "category", "pcat:448727", 
            "summary","","customer","","type","R","priority","0","znetid",affUserId,"status","**CNCL**"};